# Linux append console output to a logfile?

Tags: linux, logging, console

I know that I can let Linux to write the console output to a logfile by doing:

```
command > logfile.log
```

But this overwrites whatever was in the logfile before. How do I make it append the output to the logfile rather than overwriting it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `>>` for appending to the same logfile
for e.g `cmd1 >> logfile.log`
then use for other commnad like

```
cmd2 >> logfile.log
```

`>>` is used for append data to the file

Answer (score 7):

just replace `>` for `>>`

Answer (score 6):

Change the operator:

```
command >> logfile.log
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `command >> logfile.log`

Answer (score 2):

A couple ways:

1) Uses io piping as follows:

$> echo 'some text' >> file.txt (will be appended)

2) Using a program like sed:

$> cat file.txt

some text

$> sed -i '$ a\ here is some more text' file.txt (will also be appended, without piping)

Gl hf!

Answer (score 2):

A single greater than character `>` WRITES output to a file.

A double character `>>` APPENDS output into an existing file