# Linux writing console output to a file

Tags: linux, console, output

I have a large amount of prints on the console and I want to store them into a file. Can anyone suggest a way in Linux?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux append console output to a logfile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483012/linux-append-console-output-to-a-logfile)

Answer (score 2):

```
your_print_command > filename.txt
```

Or

```
your_print_command >> filename.txt
```

The latter appends data into file instead of overriding it.

Comment: I have a program that already printed too many lines on the console and stopped. And I want to save now what is already printed on the screen.

Comment: @avbavb For "now", just copy from console and paste into file and save. For future, take the code from above. Is it what you want? Sorr, i am in the bus, couldnot write much in answer

Comment: I can copy and paste but there are around 100000 lines of print.

Comment: @avbavb sorry i dont see any chance other than copy paste. It is because the actual output is just in buffer meaning it isnot saved anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you get both **stderr** and **stdout** to the file instead of the console

```
command_generating_text &> /path/to/file
```

To keep **stderr** and **stdout** to different files

```
command_generating_text 1> /path/to/file.stdout 2> /path/to/file.stderr
```